# ui redmond theme causing error "Failed to load resource data:"

Tags: jquery, user-interface, themes

I stripped this down to the bare essentials:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>test</title>

<script src="js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.min.js"></script>
<link href="css/redmond/jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script>

$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#dialog-form-login").dialog( {
    });
});

</script>
</head>

<body>


<div id='dialog-form-login' title='log in'>
    <p id='explain'>Please enter your username and password. If you forgot your password select the 'forgot password' button at the bottom of this window</p>
    <form id='loginform'>
        <fieldset>
            <label for='username'>username</label><br />
            <input type='text' name='username' id='username' class='text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all' /><br />
            <label for='password'>password</label><br />
            <input type='password' name='password' id='password' class='text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all' /><br />
        </fieldset>
     </form>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

I downloaded the theme from [jQueriui.com](http://jqueryui.com) and installed everything. A sample of the file can be found at [test.html](http://www.amazingjokes.com/ui/test.html).

If you load that page in safari and select "inspect element" you'll find an error: "Failed to load resource data:". I stripped just about everything I wrote myself from this test, so it's running on just the jQueryUI files. Why am I getting this error and what can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not you, it's an outstanding bug in jQuery UI Dialog (you can see it if you just use their examples on the jQuery UI website). It's fixed in trunk but I don't think the fix is released yet. Details in [the bug report](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7293). There's also a workaround in there (small change to the CSS).

Comment: Found it indeed! It's on line 309 of the theme's CSS-file (jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.css):

    background-image:url(data:);

that's obviously going to cause an error. I changed it (per the link you posted) to:


    background-image:url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAD/ACwAAAAAAQABAAACADs=);

and the error is gone. Might be a good tip for jQueryUI as well ;-). thanks!

Comment: @patrick: :-) Glad that helped. *"Might be a good tip for jQueryUI as well"* Not sure I'm following you, that link was to a jQuery UI bug report, so they're aware of it, they just haven't released the fix yet...

Comment: you're right. Saw the solution itself on google.com, figured that was something else. Anyway, thanks for the solution!